# If the speed of light is independent of motion of its emitter then what is it constant in relation to?

Tags: speed-of-light

If the speed of light is independent of motion of its emitter then that would be the same as saying that the speed of light is not constant relative to its emitter which, presumably, could move forward and backward along its beam without its velocity  affecting the speed of the beam in the slightest. That would mean that the speed of light is not constant relative to its emitter so what is it constant relative to, a privileged frame called "empty space"?

Comment: "Speed relative to the emitter" is not the same as "Speed as observed by the emitter"

Comment: Your first sentence is a non-sequitur. The speed of light is constant relative to the emitter in the emitter's frame of reference. It is also constant relative to anything else.

Answer (score 4):

In the emitter's frame,the speed of the light is $c$ relative to the emitter, but not to you.  In your frame, the speed of the light is $c$ relative to you but not to the emitter.  In either frame the speed of light is constant relative to both you and the emitter (assuming you and the emitter are both inertial).

Answer (score -5):

My answer to my question is; empty space is a privileged frame, because it would have to be if the speed of light is independent of forward and backward motion of its emitter. There are only two possibilities, either the speed of light is constant relative to its emitter or it's not and is instead constant relative to something else, which would have to be empty space. Therefore, hopefully the empty space centered grid will be set up so people can navigate through space with reliable reference coordinates.

Comment: To explain how Physics SE works, answers should not be opinions.  They should instead state the *mainstream* physics answers to the question.  Personal theories are off-topic as questions and so not usually acceptable as answers.